# Release upgrade crashes with "W:Failed to fetch http://host/debian/dists/oneiric/Release.gpg"

Tags: apt, updates

My update manager told me that it has not checked for updates in the past 18 days, so I clicked the "check" button.  It works just fine until a certain point where it says "Downloading release".  The loading bar moves across the screen for a while on that message, then it just stops and says to check my Internet connection.  I am fairly certain that my Internet is fine, as I can do anything else that I have tried, including installing software over the Internet.

I clicked on "Details" and this is what turned up: [Log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/889593)

Comment: Can you copy the output to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ then provide the link in your question?

Comment: I get a string of failed mirrors sometimes.  In my case it's ISP similar URL traffic throttling during high bandwidth utilization times.  If I pump the requests through a socks proxy the sites are up.

Comment: I pasted it to http://paste.ubuntu.com/889593/

Comment: @NolanDillard Are you sure you have regular Ubuntu installed...? It looks like you have some extremely odd repositories... As in, your package archive appears to be hosted locally. Could you say who installed your OS, what sort of prcoess (eg LiveCD/Wubi/custom respin) they used, what sort of customization you've done to the system? (Please edit your post with this information)

Comment: I personally installed it originally through a 10.04 install disk, various upgrades, then upgraded to 64 bit 11.10 via live boot USB made by Unetbootin.

Comment: What do you have in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`? That, and if you have any files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` control where Ubuntu will pick up packages. Those files seem to be hosed.

Comment: Ok.  I have just solved my own problem.  I went to http://repogen.simplylinux.ch and selected what I needed, then followed the instructions provided.  My update manager is working properly now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what i know regarding this issue is , if you dont have resolv.conf file  properly you gonna get that . I mean if your nameserver address was not mentioned there . then there is a possibility of getting that error .